# Python 2.7 Keeping track of what's been printed

Tags: python, logging, python-2.7

I'm working on a code-checker for my students (I tutor). The project is that they write a function that prints a specific string using the `print` keyword. I want to be able to test what they have printed by storing it and matching to a list (or something similar). The basic setup is:

```
def checker():
    #run user code
    do some other things like save and check error messages etc
```

Now somewhere in this `checker` function I want to be able to keep track of what was printed. In Javascript, I was able to do something like:

```
var logs = [];
var hold_logger = console.log //saves the console.log so nothing gets ruined
console.log = function (x) { logs.push(x) };
```

Now when I run the students code, instead of printing to the console, it pushes the value to `logs`. I want to achieve the same thing in Python 2.7.

Comment: You could just run it with subprocess, and you'll get a file handle on the stdout.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you teaching your students Python 2.7 instead of 3.3?

Comment: @abarnert So many bad reasons, chief among them that I don't set the curriculum.

Comment: @marisbest2: Understood. Well, if you ever do get a chance to teach 3.x, you can replace the `print` function exactly the same way you'd replace the `console.log` function in JS. It still might not be the right answer, but it's nice to have the option.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can assign a different file-like object to [`sys.stdout`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.stdout); anything that is printed is written to that object.

You can use a [`io.BytesIO()` object](http://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.BytesIO) to replace `stdout`:

```
import sys
from io import BytesIO

orig_stdout, sys.stdout = BytesIO()
```

`io` is the newer, more robust I/O library from Python 3, available in Python 2 as well; `io.BytesIO()` is the more robust version of `StringIO.StringIO()`.

You can then inspect what was printed by calling `sys.stdout.getvalue()`; when done, you can restore from `orig_stdout`.

Demo:

```
>>> import sys
>>> from io import BytesIO
>>> orig_stdout, sys.stdout = sys.stdout, BytesIO()
>>> print 'Hello world!'
>>> output = sys.stdout.getvalue()
>>> sys.stdout = orig_stdout
>>> output
'Hello world!\n'
```

Note that I restored `sys.stdout` from an earlier reference. You could also use [`sys.__stdout__`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.__stdout__), *provided nothing else replaces `sys.stdout`*; saving a reference to what `sys.stdout` is pointing to *now* is safer.

Comment: For Python3 `StringIO` should be imported like this: `from io import StringIO`

Comment: @niekas in Python 3 you can just replace the `print()` function.

Comment: In my case it is more convenient to replace whole `sys.stdout` in order to capture the final text printed out. I have multiple `print(<text>, end='')` statements and I check the the final outcome in my test.

Comment: @niekas: a custom `print()` function can still append to a shared file object. :-) Just to be clear, this question is explicitly tagged with `python-2.7`. See [this other answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34871605/stringio-portability-between-python2-and-python3-when-capturing-stdout/34872005#34872005) for a version compatible across Python 2 and 3.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way - you can replace the standard output file object with a custom one:

```
import sys

# A very basic logging class (it should really implement all the file object methods, but for your purposes, this will probably suffice.
class basicLogger:
    def __init__(self):
        self.log = []
    def write(self, msg):
        self.log.append(msg)
    def writelines(self, msgs):
        for msg in msgs:
            self.log.append(msg)

log = basicLogger()

# Replaces the default output file object with your logger
sys.stdout = log

def checker():
    #run user code
    print "hello!"
    print
    print "I am a student!"

checker()

# This replaces the original output file object.
sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__

print "Print log:"
for msg in log.log:
    print "\t", msg,
```

output:

```
Print log:
    hello!  

    I am a student!
```

Answer (score 0):

The Python equivalent of what you're doing in Java is to replace `sys.stdout` with a custom file-like object.

Of course this won't just catch what they `print`; it'll also catch what they `sys.stdout.write`, or, depending on their settings, maybe things they `logging.log` or the output of subprocesses they run, etc. But there's really no way around that, because `print` isn't a function you can replace. (Of course if you taught them 3.x instead, that would be a different story.)

---

However, it's probably simpler to not do this at all. Just capture the stdout from outside of Python. For example:

```
for student in student??.py:
    python ${student} > ${student}.out
```

Or, if you insist, do the same thing with `subprocess` from within Python:

```
output = {student: subprocess.check_output('{}.py'.format(student)) 
          for student in students}
```

(You'd probably want to wrap that in something that caught and stashed exceptions, but that should be enough to give you the idea.)